# combine two java regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

Having to use regex for the first time and although I almost achieved what I require I do not seems to be able to combine into a single statement.

I have a string of words where I wish to replace `\n` if it is not preceded by a dot OR not preceded by a dot space.

I can run either of these two statements to achieve the required result. However, if I either run them one after another or try to combine them into a single regex, it does not work.

```java
//replaces \n if not preceded by dot space
xx = xx.replaceAll("(.+)(?<!\\. )\n", "$1 ");


//replaces \n if not preceded by dot
xx = xx.replaceAll("(.+)(?<!\\.)\n", "$1 "); 


//one of my attempts to combine into a single statement
xx = xx.replaceAll("(.+)(?<!\\. )\n|(?<!\\.)\n", "$1 ");
```

Example of String I'm trying to fix.

BEFORE

```
This is some text which may\n
have a newline character to break the line\n
but I only want to remove it if it's not preceded with a full.\n
or it's not preceded with a full stop and a space. \n
```

AFTER

```
This is some text which may
have a newline character to break the line 
but I only want to remove it if it's not preceded with a full.\n
or it's not preceded with a full stop and a space. \n
```

I think I'm close, but being new to regex, I am getting more confused the more I read.

Comment: @user1706269: You can always accept answers, even with 1 rep. You do need 15 rep points to be able to upvote, though. Anyway, now you can do both :) Some SO users are very harsh on people who are new to the site - don't worry about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than you think:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?<!\\. ?)\n", " ");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!   # Assert that the previous characters are not...
 \.    # a dot
 [ ]?  # optionally followed by a space
)      # End of lookbehind
\n     # Match a newline character
```

So you don't need to match `(.+)` in the first place, only to replace it with itself afterwards. Incidentally, here's what tripped you up:

```
(.+)(?<!\. )\n|(?<!\.)\n
```

is logically grouped as

```
(.+)(?<!\. )\n   # Match this
|                # or
(?<!\.)\n        # this
```

so the `(.+)` is only matched if there is no space after the dot.

Comment: Just to add, even if the look-behind are group up, it is not going to work, since one condition can satisfy when the string encounters the other case.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Not sure what you mean but if I do `(.+)(?:(?<!\. )\n|(?<!\.)\n)` or `(.+)(?<!\. |\.)\n` (although of course both are ugly), it would work just fine.

Comment: The 2nd case will work, but the 1st case won't (I tested it), for the reason I explained above. When the regex encounter `. \n`, it fails the first one but pass the 2nd choice in the alternation, and vice versa

Comment: Thanks Tim. Ahh... so easy when you know what you're doing. When I get some time must find a good regex tutorial.

Comment: @user1706269: No need to search for long: http://www.regular-expressions.info is excellent.